# Need Alfresco Share API to allow access to custom aspect form configuration info

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have specified form configurations for my custom aspects in my amp's share-config-custom.xml file.

We are planning to use standalone UI not share interface, and I'd like to access the field-visibility & appearance information I setup for my aspects.

Since the xml file is in a share amp I'm looking for some kind of Share API to allow me to query for it.

Comment: Not clear about your requirement.can you please elaborate?

Comment: So you want to use the configs like the share-config-custom but without Share? Probably you could use Spring Surf instead.

Answer (score 1):

Go read about the [form service](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/forms-intro.html). Then look at the Share tier and repo tier web scripts that are leveraged as part of that. Your custom front-end can probably reuse those.